# Draw UIBezierPaths in UIView without subclassing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uikit, uibezierpath

I'm brand new to using UIBezierPaths to draw shapes. All of the examples I have found so far involve first subclassing a view, then overriding the `drawRect:` method and doing the drawing within there, but I haven't been able to find anything that says with absolute certainty whether this is the only way to draw UIBezierPaths within a UIView, or if this is just the most pragmatic way.

Is there any other way (besides swizzling) to draw a UIBezierPath in a UIView without subclassing it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Another way to draw bezier paths without using drawRect is to use CAShapeLayers. Set the path property of a shape layer to a CGPath created from the bezier path. Add the shape layer as a sublayer to your view's layer.

```
    UIBezierPath *shape = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:self.view.bounds];
    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.path = shape.CGPath;
    shapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.5 green:1 blue:.5 alpha:1].CGColor;
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2;

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
```

Comment: This seems like just what I was looking for! Wish I had known this yesterday =P Are there any unforeseen limitations or features of UIBezierPath that will not be accessible when doing it this way?

Comment: @n00neimp0rtant I don't know of any specific limitations, nor am I aware of what the memory consequences would be, especially if you wanted to have multiple layers. You would have to do some profiling to find out.

Answer (score 8):

Swift version of accepted answer:

```
    let shape = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: view.bounds)
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = shape.CGPath
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 1, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1).CGColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2.0
    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3 accepted answer:

```
let shape = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: view.bounds)
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path = shape.cgPath
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 1, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1).cgColor
shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2.0
view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could: 1) render UIBezierPaths into image context. 2) Add UIImageView as a subview of your view and set image property with rendered image.
Something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:self.imageView];
    [self drawPaths];
}

- (void)drawPaths {
       UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds);
       //draw...
       self.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
       UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Comment: So you would essentially render the bezier path as a UIImage, and then display it in a UIImageView? This could potentially be better than subclassing in some cases, but it does seem quite expensive, especially if it is redrawn as a view is resized.